# Request not reaching to the controller but still get 200 response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

I was playing around spring security and trying to secure an restful application, but then ran into this rather absurd problem. All the action on my controllers are fine and the requests are accepted but the request actually never reaches the controller and always 200 is returned with no content.

My security config looks likes so:

```java
package com.bpawan.interview.api.config;

import com.bpawan.interview.api.model.Error;
import com.bpawan.interview.api.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter;
import com.bpawan.interview.api.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter;
import com.bpawan.interview.service.UserDetailService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import static com.bpawan.interview.api.security.SecurityConstants.LOGIN_URL;
import static com.bpawan.interview.api.security.SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailService userDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder managerBuilder) throws Exception {
        managerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/actuator/**"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:8080");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
            var error = Error
                    .builder()
                    .message("Not authenticated")
                    .status(401)
                    .build();

            var responseBody = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(error);

            httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
            httpServletResponse.getWriter().append(responseBody);
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
        };
    }

    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return (httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, e) -> {
            var error = Error
                    .builder()
                    .message("Access denied")
                    .status(403)
                    .build();

            var responseBody = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(error);

            httpServletResponse.getWriter().append(responseBody);
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(403);
            httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

The controller looks like so:

```java
package com.bpawan.interview.api.controller;

import com.bpawan.interview.dal.entity.Candidate;
import com.bpawan.interview.dal.repository.CandidateRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/candidate")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CandidateController {
    private final CandidateRepository candidateRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Candidate> getAll(Principal principal) {

        log.info(principal.toString());

        return this.candidateRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{candidateId}")
    public Candidate getById(@PathVariable Long candidateId) {
        return this.candidateRepository
                .findById(candidateId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not find the candidate for the provided id."));
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Candidate addCandidate(@RequestBody Candidate candidate) {
        return this.candidateRepository.save(candidate);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{candidateId}")
    public void deleteCandidate(@PathVariable Long candidateId) {
        this.candidateRepository.deleteById(candidateId);
    }
}
```

The Authorization filter looks like so:

```java
package com.bpawan.interview.api.security;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.bpawan.interview.api.security.SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING;
import static com.bpawan.interview.api.security.SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX;

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final var header = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (null != header) {
            final var headerContainsPrefix = header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX);

            if (!headerContainsPrefix) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            return;
        }


        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = this.getAuthentication(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final var token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (null != token) {
            final var user = JWT
                    .require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build().verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (null != user) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can make a login request and get the valid Bearer token and seems to work with the authentication against the database.

All the actuator endpoints works fine too also the swagger endpoints. Only the controllers that I have written do not. Even when I put the breakpoints on the controllers to see if the it actually goes in there but nope.

I am feeling like I might have a silly mistake somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the sample log of the request that I did using logback-access:

```
logging uri: GET /api/candidate HTTP/1.1 | status code: 200 | bytes: 0 | elapsed time: 1 | request-log:  | response-log:
```

But cannot see the trace on the actuator's endpoint `actuator/httptrace` whatsoever as if the request ever happened.

Comment: Use `ResponseEntity<List<Candidate>>` as return type for `getAll`. Also change the others to use `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani Thanks for the comment but it does not help. I don't think the problem is on the return types of the controllers.

Comment: Maybe adding `/` before the path could help: `@RequestMapping("/api/candidate")`

Comment: nope does not make any difference.

Comment: Just to ensure, please change the getAll mapping path to another thing then call `/api/candidate` again

Comment: Good idea. Confirmed the request actually never goes to controllers. calling `http://localhost:8080/foo` also return 200.

Comment: Inside JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal() if headerContainsPrefix is true then you are simply returning and not calling next filters in the filter chain. I suspect you are receiving the response from that point.

Comment: @Ajinkya yes your were absolutely correct.

Comment: Can you let me answer that? And then accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: sure, I have added the answer too. if you have a better than mine. Of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After struggling some time I found the problem. It was indeed a stupid mistake that I made. and it was on the Authorization filter. changed

```java
 if (null != header) {
            final var headerContainsPrefix = header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX);

            if (!headerContainsPrefix) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
```

to :

```java
 if (null != header) {
            final var headerContainsPrefix = header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX);

            if (!headerContainsPrefix) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
        }
```

and seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass on the request on to the chain and you don't in case (header != null && headerContainsprefix)

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer will help someone.

In my case I had a custom filter `JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` for a Jwt-token. I ovverided only one method:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        final JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = parseJwt(request);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(jwtAuthenticationToken);
    }
```

After successfully parsing request and token and returning a valid authenticate object `Authentication`, the request did not reach the controller, but returned status 200 with empty body.

Then overriding the following method in class `JwtAuthenticationFilter` worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authResult);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```