# Spring Boot REST API accepts all requests and returns blank responses

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

When using Postman or making requests from Angular frontend I always got blank/null responses with `200 OK` from backend even on wrong routes.

security config:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

for example, checking if username is taken:

```
    @GetMapping("/available")
    public Boolean isUsernameTaken(@RequestParam String username) {
        return userService.isUsernameTaken(username);
    }
```

does not even get inside this method, but code returned is `200`.

Making requests on wrong endpoint `http://localhost:8080/fakeEndpoint/xxxxx` also returns blank page and code 200.

Comment: I  had a quick search for issues related to yours. The one that pops out at me is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722709/request-not-reaching-to-the-controller-but-still-get-200-response. Do you have an Authorization filter? 
Additionally, comment on similar question: `Inside JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal() if headerContainsPrefix is true then you are simply returning and not calling next filters in the filter chain. I suspect you are receiving the response from that point.`

Comment: It provided good direction to find cause. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The problem was in custom filter class that extends `OncePerRequestFilter`. Overriden `doFilterInternal()` method was executed, but without chaining filtering - I did not call `filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse)` at the end of this method.